# Indefinite integral $ \int \frac{\log\Gamma(\frac{x}{2})}{x^2}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, gamma-function

I want to compute the indefinite integral
$$ \int  \frac{\log\Gamma(\frac{x}{2})}{x^2}\,dx, $$
but fail myself. Do you know how to compute this integral?

Comment: have you studied series and sequences?

Comment: I think that  does not have finite closed-form expression in terms of very large class of special functions.Only hope is comment by: `H_K` user. With series: $\int \frac{\text{log$\Gamma $}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{x^2} \, dx=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{\pi ^2 x}{48}+\frac{\pi ^4
   x^3}{17280}-\frac{\log (2)}{x}-\frac{1}{2} \gamma  \log (x)+\frac{\log (x)}{x}+\frac{x^2 \psi
   ^{(2)}(1)}{96}+\frac{x^4 \psi ^{(4)}(1)}{15360}+C+...+$

Comment: so what's the problem? Could you please point out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [Weirstrass formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Weierstrass%27s_definition) ,   $$\log \Gamma(x)=-\gamma x-\log(x)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( \frac{x}{n}-\log\left( 1+\frac{x}{n}\right) \right).$$